# Interpreting the psych::cor.smoother function

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, psych

I've tried to contact William Revelle about this but he isn't responding.

In the *psych* package there is a function called cor.smoother, which determines whether or not a correlation matrix is positive definite. Its explanation is as follows:

"**cor.smoother examines all of nvar minors of rank nvar-1 by systematically dropping one variable at a time and finding the eigen value decomposition.** It reports those variables, which, when dropped, produce a positive definite matrix. It also reports the number of negative eigenvalues when each variable is dropped. Finally, it compares the original correlation matrix to the smoothed correlation matrix and reports those items with absolute deviations great than cut. These are all hints as to what might be wrong with a correlation matrix."

It is the really the statement in bold that I am hoping someone can interpret in a more understandable way for me?

Comment: This looks like a linear algebra question to me. see the following wikipedia link on [minor matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29). Your question is probably better suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

A belated answer to your question.

Correlation matrices are said to be improper (or more accurately, not positive semi-definite) when at least one of the eigen values of the matrix is less than 0.  This can happen if you have some missing data and are using pair-wise complete correlations.  It is particularly likely to happen if you are doing tetrachoric or polychoric  correlations based upon data sets with some or even a lot of missing data.

(A correlation matrix, R,  may be decomposed into a set of eigen vectors (X) and eigen values (lambda) where R =  X lambda X’.  This decomposition is the basis of components analysis and factor analysis, but that is more than you want to know.)

The cor.smooth function finds the eigen values and then adjusts the negative ones by making them slightly positive (and adjusting the other ones to compensate for this change).

The cor.smoother function attempts to identify the variables that are making the matrix improper.  It does this by considering all the matrices generated by dropping one variable at a time and seeing which ones of those are not positive semi-definite (i.e. have eigen values < 0.)  Ideally, this will identify one variable that is messing things up.

An example of this is in the burt data set where the sorrow-tenderness correlation was probably mistyped and the .87 should be .81.

cor.smoother(burt)  #identifies tenderness and sorrow as likely culprits